# C++ check is struct is empty

Tags: c++

Hi have an external library function which has the following function:

```
struct ImageData {
  int rows;
  int cols;
  int max_val;
  std::vector<int> data;
};

/// Reads from a pgm image from ascii file. Returns empty ImageData if the path
/// is not found or any errors have occured while reading.
ImageData ReadFromPgm(const std::string& file_name);
```

When doing some processing after calling this function I need a way to tell what an "empty ImageData" is, something along the lines of:

```
ImageData read_from_pgm = ReadFromPgm(some_file);
if (read_from_pgm is empty) { //do something }
else{ //do something else }
```

Comment: Since we have no further information of the API you are using we can just make some assumptions. Maybe a simple check like `read_from_pgm.rows <= 0`, `read_from_pgm.cols <= 0` or `read_from_pgm.data.size() <= 0` will solve the problem?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Would this be acceptable? What happens if the values are NULL or something else?

Comment: read_from_pgm can't be null, since it is not a pointer (also it's fields).

Comment: Ok thanks, still getting used to C++ from python, which now seems like the wild wild west.

Comment: Are you interested in seeing if the `data` vector is null, or if the whole thing is just empty?

Comment: You can see from the first code snippet that it "returns an empty ImageData", i'm interested in checking whatever that means.

Comment: Is this the only information you have? No further API documentation?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg No other documentation, i only have the .h file and the .so object file. I thought the returned object may be ```ImageData returnedData = {};``` if it was empty. Is this possible?

Comment: @chipster: Vector can't be null either. It can be empty, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no further API documentation we can only make an assumption. Most likely,  *empty ImageData* means the default (initialized) value for the `ImageData` type (`ImageData id = { }`);. This means default values for all of it's fields. In this case you can do a simple check:

```
ImageData read_from_pgm = ReadFromPgm(some_file);
if (read_from_pgm.rows == 0
    && read_from_pgm.cols == 0
    && read_from_pgm.max_val == 0
    && read_from_pgm.data.size() == 0)
{ //Image is empty }
```

Note that it's not absolutely necessary to check all fields. I think checking only `rows` or `data.size()` should be also OK, since a valid image should always contains some rows or data.